# JQuery .slideToggle - click on one element and it shows all hidden elements

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

This is probably an incredibly silly question with an obvious answer, and I think I may be wrong in using slideToggle, but I wasn't sure how else to do it.

Essentially, I would like a user to click on different headings to hide/reveal only the paragraph below. At the moment, if you click on any of the headings, it reveals all the hidden paragraphs.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
<a href="#"><div class="contenthead">
    Click here
</div></a>
<p class="content"> Lorem ipsum dolor</p>


<a href="#"><div class="contenthead">
    Click here now
</div></a>
<p class="content"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</p>


<script>
$('.contenthead').click(function() {
    $('.content').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
});
</script>
```

Any ideas how I can do this please?

Comment: You'd better not put `<div>` in `<a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)() and [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)() functions.

```
$('.contenthead').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Comment: @user1576659 no prob, dont forget to accept the answer when you can!

Answer (score 0):

See you need a jquery plugin at the top and below this script:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'>
</script>

<script>
$(function(){ //<------------------------ use doc ready handler
   $('.contenthead').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle('slow');
   });
});          //<-------------------------
</script>
```